# Names all taken on Azure Data Factory Instance creation

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a new instance of a Data Factory in Microsoft Azure, but it keeps telling me that that name is taken. Doesn't matter what I put, mashing on the keys to get 20 random characters (all numbers and letters) it says that it's already taken. Husband just tried, too, same problem. Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an intermittent error as I am able to create ADF :
[image]

Can you please refresh the cache and please try again. And it would be great if you provide screenshot of the names and error is it persists.

FOr now, please try the above name as I have not actually created it and confirm back.

Comment: Can't add a screenshot because apparently I am too new. I did try your exact Name after clearing cache but it's still not working. Figured out a work-around, creating a data factory using the Azure Powershell, so I think it was just a GUI error or something.

Answer (score 0):

Im super late to the party. had same problem just with Service bus.

fix: create it while you are in incognito / private browser.